# Use Scrollbar with QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar, qt5

Currently I have this code to add several QLineEdits to `ui.widget` but I also need a vertical scrollbar in case of too many elements -> limited space available:

```
QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout(ui.widget);

int rowIndex = 0, colIndex = 0;
for(auto number : m_numbers)
{
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
    gridLayout->addWidget(lineEdit, rowIndex, colIndex, Qt::AlignLeft);

    if(colIndex == 7)
    {
        colIndex = 0;
        ++rowIndex;
    }
    else ++colIndex;
}
ui.widget->setLayout(gridLayout);
```

How can I make it scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

Use [QScrollBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollbar.html) : The QScrollBar widget provides a vertical or horizontal scroll bar.

define a fix size for your widget and if user create too much QLineEdit, add your customized QScrollBar to that widget.

```
QScrollBar * scroll = new QScrollBar(Qt::Vertical, ui->widget);
```

OR use [QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html) like this image: [image: Screenshot]

This is a sample project for your question on [github download here](https://github.com/FarhadProfessional/QScrollArea).